# AJAX Post Abort From Within Replaced Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Goals:

Complete: Refresh a div on my page via AJAX post every 5 seconds

Incomplete - When a dropdown menu on the refreshed div is open, stop refreshing the div. When the dropdown menu is closed on the refreshed div, commence refreshing.

With my current code, the abort_refresh() function does not seem to be aborting the ajax request. Does any happen to know how to get this working?

This is the java script code I currently have:

```
    function refresh_recent() {
        var ajaxFn = $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo site_url('/dashboard/recent'); ?>',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data : 'none',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    $('#recent').html(data);
                    setTimeout(refresh_recent, 5000);
                }
            });
        return ajaxFn;
    }

    var refresh_object = refresh_recent();


    function abort_refresh() {
        refresh_object.abort();
    }

    function start_refresh() {
        refresh_object = refresh_recent()
    }
```

"Refreshed Content" JavaScript & HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.refresh').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
        abort_refresh();
    });

    $('.refresh').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        start_refresh();
    });
</script>    

    <div class="refresh btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" data-type="outbound" data-record="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="caret"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resend-modal" data-record="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>Resend</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-outbound-modal" data-record="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You do realize that once it hits setTimeout(refresh_recent, 5000); it's going to continue executing every 5 seconds even if you call abort on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you do not update the variable that holds the Ajax request. `refresh_object` does not always have the latest request. Plus you need to cancel the timeout.

```
(function() {

    var refresh_object, timer;

    function refresh_recent() {

        if (refresh_object) return;

        var ajaxFn = $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo site_url('/dashboard/recent'); ?>',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data : 'none',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    $('#recent').html(data);
                    timer = setTimeout(refresh_recent, 5000);
                    refresh_object  = null;
                }
            });
        refresh_object = ajaxFn;
    }


    refresh_recent();


    function abort_refresh() {            
        if (refresh_object ) { 
            refresh_object.abort();
        }
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        refresh_object = null;
    }

    function start_refresh() {
        refresh_recent()
    }

    $('.refresh')
        .on('shown.bs.dropdown', abort_refresh)
        .on('hide.bs.dropdown', start_refresh);

}());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this clarified much of my confusion. Of course, my only issue now seems to be that if I do not click the dropdown menu during the post it seems to create another instance of the object and begins double posting.

Comment: Is something else triggering `refresh_recent`?